# How to send the informations received from the form to a button link that will store them, and will show them on click?

Tags: javascript, html

i am working on something and i just got stuck here. I want to send the informations i receive from filling the form to a button created with js and when i press that button, they need to be showed on the same page (i divided my body to col-3 for the forms i will get- the inputs will be stored there, and the remaining col-9 i want to use to show those informations after pressing on each button.

The form:

```
<form class="container jumbotron">
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
            <label for="FirstName">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="FirstName" required>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
            <label for="LastName">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="LastName" required>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2 mb-3">
              <label for="Age">Age</label>
              <input type="number" class="form-control" id="Age" required>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2 mb-3">
            <label for="Sex">Sex</label>
            <select class="custom-select" id="validationDefault04" required>
              <option selected disabled value="">Select gender</option>
              <option value="Male">Male</option>
              <option value="Female">Female</option>
            </select>
          </div>
    </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
                <label for="City">Address</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Address" required>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
                <label for="PhoneNumber">Phone Number</label>
                <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="PhoneNumber" required>
              </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
                <label for="Email">Email</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="Email" required>
              </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
                <label for="Email">Secondary Email</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="Email">
              </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
            <label for="date">Birthday</label><br>
            <input type="date" id="datemax" class="form-control" name="datemax" min="1900-01-01" max="2020-01-01" required>           
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="invalidCheck2" required>
            <label class="form-check-label" for="invalidCheck2">
              I agree to terms and conditions
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Add new contact</button>       
      </form>
```

And this is the code for creating the buttons

```
 function myFunction() {
 var para = document.createElement("button");
 para.innerText = "Hristijan Bosheski";
 document.body.appendChild(para);
 linebreak = document.createElement("br");
 document.body.appendChild(linebreak);
 var para = document.createElement("button");
 para.innerText = "Hristijan Bosheski";
 document.body.appendChild(para);
 linebreak = document.createElement("br");
 document.body.appendChild(linebreak);
 var para = document.createElement("button");
 para.innerText = "Hristijan Bosheski";
 document.body.appendChild(para);
 linebreak = document.createElement("br");
 document.body.appendChild(linebreak);
 var para = document.createElement("button");
 para.innerText = "Hristijan Bosheski";
 document.body.appendChild(para);
 linebreak = document.createElement("br");
 document.body.appendChild(linebreak);
 var para = document.createElement("button");
 para.innerText = "Hristijan Bosheski";
 document.body.appendChild(para);
 linebreak = document.createElement("br");
 document.body.appendChild(linebreak);
 var para = document.createElement("button");
 para.innerText = "Hristijan Bosheski";
 document.body.appendChild(para);
```

}
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: and what is the problem that you are facing here :)

Comment: This form doesn't get sent anywhere, and my goal is to make buttons like those shown - those are just templates for now, and after every succesfull form fill, and by pressing the buttons, informations entered in the form to be shown on the screen

Comment: you are asking lot any how adding a link give it a try yourself first.  https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OliverPaljak/JSDynamicFormContent/master/examples/dynamic-single-form-content-example.html